# displaying an array but it return empty

Tags: laravel

Good day, i have a laravel 5.8 project and i'm having a little problem 
i have this code

```
public function doctor_details($doctor_id){

$doctor = DB::table('doctors')->select('specification')->where('doctor_id', $doctor_id)->get>first(); 

$specs_data = explode(',', $doctor_specs);
$specs_array = [];

foreach ($specs_data as $doctor_spec) {

    $doctor_spec_result =  DB::table('specializations')->where { return explode('speciality_id'',', $doctor_spec)->get();

    foreach ($doctor_spec_result as $doctor_spec_res) {

        $specs_array[] = $doctor_spec_res->speciality_name;

    }  
 }

return view ('doctor_details', compact('doctor', 'specs_array'));
```

}

now if i do dd($doctor_spec_result); the result is
[image]

as you can see i'm getting an empty array but if i do dd($specs_data); the result is 
[image]

as you can see there's definitely a data but i can't make it work

this is my blade

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
         <h3>{{ $doctor->doctor_name }}</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-12">
         @foreach( $specs_array as $spec_output )
             <p>{!! $spec_output !!}</p>
         @endforeach
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: should there only be one doctor by `doctor_id` ... is it a key?  is `$doctor` a model instance representing the `doctors` table?

Comment: is `speciality` a field that can contain a comma separated list of ids? trying to figure out why the `explode`

Comment: yes it some of the records has two ids @lagbox

Comment: is `doctor_id` unique on the `doctors` table?

Comment: @lagbox, yes it is a primary key from the doctors table, it's from my index page i passed the id to a link to another page to display the doctor's full info, this includes the specialities.

Comment: probably shouldn't update your question to use the answer in it, doesn't let people see what the original problem was

Comment: @lagbox yes you're right, sorry about that i'd returned it to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get an list only containing the values of the `specification` field for the particular rows queried, so that you can then get the `specialty_name`s. You can use the `pluck` method on the builder to do this for you. If a search by `doctor_id` **could** return more than one result:

```
$doctor_specs = DB::table('doctors')
    ->where('doctor_id', $doctor_id)
    ->pluck('specification')
    ->transform(function ($item) { return explode(',', $item); })
    ->flatten();

$specs_array = DB::table('specializations')
    // use whereIn to find all the rows by 'specialty_id'
    ->whereIn('speciality_id', $doctor_specs)
    ->pluck('specialty_name')
    ->toArray();

return view ('doctor_details', compact('doctor', 'specs_array'));
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Database - Query Builder - Retrieving Results](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#retrieving-results) `pluck`

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Methods - `transform`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-transform)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Methods - `flatten`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-flatten)

**Update:**

Though since `doctor_id` is a key there will only be one, we can remove the collection methods and deal with this simpler:

```
$doctor_specs = explode(
    ',',
    DB::table('doctors')->where('doctor_id', $doctor_id)
        ->value('specification')
);
```

**Ideally**:

Or if `$doctor` was retrieved with all columns from the `doctors` table, including `specification`:

```
$doctor_specs = explode(',', $doctor->specification);
```

Comment: @JamesRussel I updated it now that I know there will only be one `doctor` by `doctor_id` ... can you check to make sure this version works for you still?

Comment: the updated answer is giving me no result, the last one was perfect, and again thank, thank you so much, i'm only in my first few months learning laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code using join

```
$doctor_spec_result = DB::table('doctors')
->select('specializations.speciality_name')
->join('specializations','specializations.speciality_id','doctors.specification')
->where('doctors.doctor_id', $doctor_id)
->get();

return view ('doctor_details', compact('doctor', 'doctor_spec_result '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in this line.

```
 $doctor_spec_result = DB::table('specializations')->where('speciality_id', $doctor_spec)->get();
```

you are checking the worng attribute. As you are getting specification in 0 index.

```
speciality_id to specification
```